# Spawning random fruits in Snake Game

Tags: java

I am trying to spawn random colour fruits for a snake game I developed.

However instead of the fruits spawning with a different colour every time, [it blinks at random.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZpgG.png)

Here is the code I used:

```
private void drawTile(int x, int y, TileType type, Graphics g) {
    /*
     * Because each type of tile is drawn differently, it's easiest
     * to just run through a switch statement rather than come up with some
     * overly complex code to handle everything.
     */

    switch (type) {

    /*
     * A fruit is depicted as a small red circle that with a bit of padding
     * on each side.
     */
        case Fruit:
            Random rn = new Random();
            int answer = rn.nextInt(4) + 1;

            switch (answer) {
                case 1:
                    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    g.setColor(Color.red);
                    break;
                default:
                    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    break;
            }

            g.fillOval(x + 2, y + 2, TILE_SIZE - 4, TILE_SIZE - 4);
            break;
```

I think it blinks at random because the screen is constantly refreshing.

Comment: You pretty much gave the answer yourself: "I think it blinks at random because the screen is constantly refreshing.".  You want to set the color iff. it was not yet set, therefore you need some logic to check if the color of a fruit was set before.

Comment: Yeah I know what is causing it. However I am not fully mature with Java, been trying a lot of ways to go over this but haven't found a way.

Comment: @Turing85 I can send you the code if you would like to check it out.

Comment: Well... in this case I would recommend to take a step back, [read some tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) and not start with GUI programs since they tend to get complicated rather fast.

Comment: Been through a ton of tutorials, this is my final project. I now am fluent with the basics. Got the game running, but been stuck here with this for the past 2 days.

Comment: You have to create some sort of structure to store each fruit you spawn so whenever everything gets updated you redraw then again. Don't forget to remove the fruits from this structure when the snack eats it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @Turing85 and Jorge Campos. Will try something.